# Failed to build iconv gem on ruby 1.9.2

Tags: macos, rubygems, ruby-1.9, iconv

I fail to install the 'iconv' gem, because of weird build errors.
I have build the 'libiconv' from source and linked the .h and .dylib into the rvm's include and lib directory.
When I run

```
gem install iconv
```

Gem outputs strange build errors:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for iconv() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv() in -liconv... yes
checking for const of iconv() 2nd argument... no
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.4.0 -I/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o iconv.o -c iconv.c
In file included from iconv.c:21:
/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/st.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/st.h" instead of bare "st.h"
iconv.c:22:20: error: intern.h: No such file or directory
iconv.c: In function ‘map_charset’:
iconv.c:139: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c:139: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c:142: error: ‘struct RHash’ has no member named ‘tbl’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_create’:
iconv.c:187: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:188: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:190: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:192: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:193: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_fail’:
iconv.c:328: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_fail_retry’:
iconv.c:352: error: ‘ruby_errinfo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
iconv.c:352: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
iconv.c:352: error: for each function it appears in.)
iconv.c: In function ‘rb_str_derive’:
iconv.c:371: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:371: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:373: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:373: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:374: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_convert’:
iconv.c:418: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:418: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:436: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:437: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:455: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
iconv.c:458: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
iconv.c:459: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
iconv.c:491: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c:494: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c:497: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:498: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:499: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:501: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
iconv.c:502: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
iconv.c:514: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
iconv.c: In function ‘iconv_s_convert’:
iconv.c:615: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
make: *** [iconv.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/iconv-0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/gems/iconv-0.1/ext/iconv/gem_make.out
```

How do I make it install and build properly.

Thanks

Comment: Ruby 1.9 includes the equivalent of the `iconv` gem by default. You should not need the gem. The errors, especially the “no member named …” errors, indicate that the gem is not compatible with Ruby 1.9 (many of the structs for the built-in types were, well, restructured).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found out why !
Looks like the Iconv gem is not yet 1.9.x compliant, so it will not build.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth - I was able to build 1.9.2 p136 using RVM and linking to libiconv I installed with Homebrew. This allowed me to use the JSON gem without problems. I wrote a quick blog post about it here: http://www.v25media.com/blog/read/forcing_ruby_1_9_2_via_rvm_to_use_iconv but the gist of it is:

```
$ brew install libiconv
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
```

Comment: @louism take it up with the Ruby maintainers, not me.

Comment: I should've said "you don't need to" ... look at the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was just installing iconv for mechanize so I could run script

I already had libiconv installed w/ brew

`gem install iconv -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1`

herp derp

Answer (score 3):

Why/how did you build iconv ? And more importantly, where did you install it ? Because I think gem can find the system libiconv but fails to find the headers because they're not in the normal search paths.

A few suggestions:

Easiest way is probably to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and install iconv with that: `sudo port install libiconv`

Or if you want/need to install your own version, make sure it gets installed in the `/usr/local` subtree (it's meant for software that an administrator compiled which is exactly what you're doing). So you should end up with `/usr/local/include/iconv.h` and `/usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. My freshly installed OS X 10.6 didn't have `iconv`, so I downloaded iconv from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libiconv/ and ran

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Installed fine, iconv.h and libiconv.dylib are where they're supposed to be, but gem installation `rvm gem install iconv` fails with the same errors.

I don't have enough C-fu in me to interpret the problem any further, but I would guess this could be a result of some sort of version mismatch? Maybe the `iconv` gem expects to have some older version of `libiconv`? I'd like to get some confirmation either way with this, before I fudge my system up with random versions of `iconv`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Lion these two lines work:

> brew install libiconv
>
> brew link libiconv

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the suggestions by @DarkDust and @Vee does it for me:

```
sudo port install libiconv
gem install iconv -- --with-iconv-dir=/opt/local
```

You can run

```
port contents libiconv
```

to that `libiconv` is now installed under `/opt/local/include/` and `/opt/local/include/lib`. I should also mention that I'm using ruby 1.9.3p286.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the iconv rvm package and then reinstall ruby 1.9.2:

```
$ rvm pkg install iconv
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```