# Fresh Rails 3.1 install failing...uninitialized constant JSON::ParserError

Tags: rvm, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bundler

I am using RVM and have installed rails 3.1.0 multiple times but once I begin using it I get the same error over and over again.

From a fresh install of rails 3.1.0 I do the following:

```
rails new fishapp

cd fishapp

bundle install

rails g scaffold Fish name:string

bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

But each time I go to http://localhost:3000/fish I get:

```
Showing /Users/me/code/rails31/fishapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

uninitialized constant JSON::ParserError
  (in /Users/me/code/rails31/fishapp/app/assets/javascripts/fish.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Fishapp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

I must have broke something trying to get rails installed or something as I don't otherwise understand why it would fail of a fresh install. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I simply commented out line #6 (just so I could keep working).

```
<%#= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Eventually I needed javascript, so I had to return to this issue. I kept the line above commented out, and just hard-coded this one immediately below it:

```
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The page loaded fine, so I viewed the page's source, and looked at

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/application.js
```

... only to find a similar error:

```
throw Error("NameError: uninitialized constant JSON::ParserError
(in /Users/me/Dev/fishapp/app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee)")
```

So I decided to load a rails console and see if I could load the JSON gem, but got an error with iconv:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'json'
LoadError: no such file to load -- iconv
```

Meanwhile loading the rails gem produced:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > require 'rails'
 => false
```

So I searched around and found this:

http://beginrescueend.com/packages/iconv/

Follow those instructions, and your problem will be resolved! For the record, those instructions are:

```
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

I'm leaving the steps I took in case others search Google for similar errors.

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616128/failed-to-build-iconv-gem-on-ruby-1-9-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616128/failed-to-build-iconv-gem-on-ruby-1-9-2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do some of these to see if it helps,

- Check your Gemfile to ensure you have `gem coffee script` there.
- Check your Gemfile.lock file to make sure all your dependencies are satisfied. You should probably have `multi_json` under activesupport.
- You could also try to doing an rvm get head before installing rails 3.1 and doing your bundle install to see if that helps.